# How to send big array of binary data over socket?

Tags: c, sockets, binary-data

I'm trying to send binary data from a server to a client over a socket (my application uses OpenSSL so I am using SSL_write).

The size is ~3,65MB.

However the server fails everytime the file is requested by the client and the server program terminates.

The underlying socket is a regular IPv4 TCP/IP socket...

I checked the binary_buffer and it contains data, so it's not empty.

So my question is, how can I send this buffer to the client over the socket, is there a special way to handle the sending of such big data?

```
        FILE *fpp;
        if(!(fpp = fopen("./abinary.bin", "rb"))){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error opening abinary.bin.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        unsigned char *binary_buffer;

        fseek(fpp, 0, SEEK_END);
        unsigned long fileLength = ftell(fpp);
        fseek(fpp, 0, SEEK_SET);

        binary_buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc((fileLength) * sizeof(unsigned char));
        if(!binary_buffer){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error allocation memory for binary_buffer.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        fread(binary_buffer, fileLength, 1, fpp);

        SSL_write(ssl, binary_buffer, fileLength);
```

Comment: what does SSL_write return? If it returns an error, what does SSL_get_error say?

Comment: You have to get the return value from SSL_write to see how many bytes it actually sent.  If it sent fewer than the amount you wanted to send (and if you wanted to send megabytes, it almost certainly will), then you need to call it again with updated arguments to send more bytes.  Repeat until you've sent the whole array.

Comment: You say the server fails, yet you suspect the client is at fault. Why is that?